# Time series with missing data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Below you can find a dataset. There are 20 missing values in the time series, represented by NaN. Could you please show me how to write a python-3 script to get your best estimates of the NaN values?

Notice that you need to account for the fact that dates and times are not equally spaced, so you cannot just take the average between the previous and next value (here times are always 16:00:00, but it is not necessarily true for other datasets, so I would like to see a general solution that accounts also for non-equally-spaced times).

Could you please show me a general code that uses pandas and can tackle my previous point? Can you please assume in your solution that your input is a list of strings, e.g. ['1/3/2012 16:00:00    26.96', '1/4/2012 16:00:00   27.47', ...] . There is a space between date and time, and a tab between time and value.

For the below data, the ideal 20 NaN values should be: [26.96, 32.15, 32.61, 29.3, 28.96, 28.78, 31.05, 29.58, 29.5, 30.9, 31.26, 31.48, 29.74, 29.31, 29.72, 28.88, 30.2, 27.3, 26.7, 27.52]

```
1/3/2012 16:00:00   NaN
1/4/2012 16:00:00   27.47
1/5/2012 16:00:00   27.728
1/6/2012 16:00:00   28.19
1/9/2012 16:00:00   28.1
1/10/2012 16:00:00  28.15
1/11/2012 16:00:00  27.98
1/12/2012 16:00:00  28.02
1/13/2012 16:00:00  28.25
1/17/2012 16:00:00  28.65
1/18/2012 16:00:00  28.4
1/19/2012 16:00:00  28.435
1/20/2012 16:00:00  29.74
1/23/2012 16:00:00  29.95
1/24/2012 16:00:00  29.5703
1/25/2012 16:00:00  29.65
1/26/2012 16:00:00  29.7
1/27/2012 16:00:00  29.53
1/30/2012 16:00:00  29.62
1/31/2012 16:00:00  29.7
2/1/2012 16:00:00   30.05
2/2/2012 16:00:00   30.17
2/3/2012 16:00:00   30.4
2/6/2012 16:00:00   30.22
2/7/2012 16:00:00   30.485
2/8/2012 16:00:00   30.67
2/9/2012 16:00:00   30.8
2/10/2012 16:00:00  30.8
2/13/2012 16:00:00  30.77
2/14/2012 16:00:00  30.46
2/15/2012 16:00:00  30.39
2/16/2012 16:00:00  31.55
2/17/2012 16:00:00  31.32
2/21/2012 16:00:00  31.61
2/22/2012 16:00:00  31.68
2/23/2012 16:00:00  31.59
2/24/2012 16:00:00  31.5
2/27/2012 16:00:00  31.5
2/28/2012 16:00:00  31.93
2/29/2012 16:00:00  32
3/1/2012 16:00:00   32.39
3/2/2012 16:00:00   32.44
3/5/2012 16:00:00   32.05
3/6/2012 16:00:00   31.98
3/7/2012 16:00:00   31.92
3/8/2012 16:00:00   32.21
3/9/2012 16:00:00   32.16
3/12/2012 16:00:00  32.2
3/13/2012 16:00:00  32.69
3/14/2012 16:00:00  32.88
3/15/2012 16:00:00  32.94
3/16/2012 16:00:00  32.95
3/19/2012 16:00:00  32.61
3/20/2012 16:00:00  32.15
3/21/2012 16:00:00  NaN
3/22/2012 16:00:00  32.09
3/23/2012 16:00:00  32.11
3/26/2012 16:00:00  NaN
3/27/2012 16:00:00  32.7
3/28/2012 16:00:00  32.7
3/29/2012 16:00:00  32.19
3/30/2012 16:00:00  32.41
4/2/2012 16:00:00   32.46
4/3/2012 16:00:00   32.19
4/4/2012 16:00:00   31.69
4/5/2012 16:00:00   31.63
4/9/2012 16:00:00   31.4
4/10/2012 16:00:00  31.19
4/11/2012 16:00:00  30.53
4/12/2012 16:00:00  31.04
4/13/2012 16:00:00  31.16
4/16/2012 16:00:00  31.19
4/17/2012 16:00:00  31.61
4/18/2012 16:00:00  31.31
4/19/2012 16:00:00  31.68
4/20/2012 16:00:00  32.89
4/23/2012 16:00:00  32.5
4/24/2012 16:00:00  32.52
4/25/2012 16:00:00  32.32
4/26/2012 16:00:00  32.23
4/27/2012 16:00:00  32.22
4/30/2012 16:00:00  32.11
5/1/2012 16:00:00   32.335
5/2/2012 16:00:00   31.925
5/3/2012 16:00:00   31.9
5/4/2012 16:00:00   31.57
5/7/2012 16:00:00   30.86
5/8/2012 16:00:00   30.78
5/9/2012 16:00:00   30.83
5/10/2012 16:00:00  31.02
5/11/2012 16:00:00  31.54
5/14/2012 16:00:00  31.04
5/15/2012 16:00:00  30.795
5/16/2012 16:00:00  30.32
5/17/2012 16:00:00  30.2084
5/18/2012 16:00:00  29.81
5/21/2012 16:00:00  29.79
5/22/2012 16:00:00  29.88
5/23/2012 16:00:00  29.4
5/24/2012 16:00:00  NaN
5/25/2012 16:00:00  29.36
5/29/2012 16:00:00  29.72
5/30/2012 16:00:00  29.479
5/31/2012 16:00:00  29.42
6/1/2012 16:00:00   NaN
6/4/2012 16:00:00   NaN
6/5/2012 16:00:00   28.75
6/6/2012 16:00:00   29.37
6/7/2012 16:00:00   29.7
6/8/2012 16:00:00   29.68
6/11/2012 16:00:00  29.81
6/12/2012 16:00:00  29.3
6/13/2012 16:00:00  29.44
6/14/2012 16:00:00  29.46
6/15/2012 16:00:00  30.08
6/18/2012 16:00:00  30.03
6/19/2012 16:00:00  31.11
6/20/2012 16:00:00  31.05
6/21/2012 16:00:00  31.14
6/22/2012 16:00:00  30.73
6/25/2012 16:00:00  30.32
6/26/2012 16:00:00  30.27
6/27/2012 16:00:00  30.5
6/28/2012 16:00:00  30.05
6/29/2012 16:00:00  30.69
7/2/2012 16:00:00   30.62
7/3/2012 16:00:00   30.76
7/5/2012 16:00:00   30.78
7/6/2012 16:00:00   30.7
7/9/2012 16:00:00   30.23
7/10/2012 16:00:00  30.22
7/11/2012 16:00:00  29.735
7/12/2012 16:00:00  29.18
7/13/2012 16:00:00  29.48
7/16/2012 16:00:00  29.53
7/17/2012 16:00:00  29.86
7/18/2012 16:00:00  30.45
7/19/2012 16:00:00  30.8
7/20/2012 16:00:00  NaN
7/23/2012 16:00:00  NaN
7/24/2012 16:00:00  29.36
7/25/2012 16:00:00  29.33
7/26/2012 16:00:00  NaN
7/27/2012 16:00:00  29.85
7/30/2012 16:00:00  29.82
7/31/2012 16:00:00  29.71
8/1/2012 16:00:00   29.65
8/2/2012 16:00:00   29.525
8/3/2012 16:00:00   29.94
8/6/2012 16:00:00   30.11
8/7/2012 16:00:00   30.35
8/8/2012 16:00:00   30.47
8/9/2012 16:00:00   30.65
8/10/2012 16:00:00  30.62
8/13/2012 16:00:00  30.46
8/14/2012 16:00:00  30.39
8/15/2012 16:00:00  30.28
8/16/2012 16:00:00  30.94
8/17/2012 16:00:00  30.92
8/20/2012 16:00:00  30.85
8/21/2012 16:00:00  30.96
8/22/2012 16:00:00  30.76
8/23/2012 16:00:00  30.4
8/24/2012 16:00:00  30.63
8/27/2012 16:00:00  30.96
8/28/2012 16:00:00  30.8
8/29/2012 16:00:00  30.75
8/30/2012 16:00:00  30.61
8/31/2012 16:00:00  30.96
9/4/2012 16:00:00   30.66
9/5/2012 16:00:00   30.53
9/6/2012 16:00:00   31.36
9/7/2012 16:00:00   31.07
9/10/2012 16:00:00  NaN
9/11/2012 16:00:00  30.91
9/12/2012 16:00:00  31.18
9/13/2012 16:00:00  31.18
9/14/2012 16:00:00  31.25
9/17/2012 16:00:00  NaN
9/18/2012 16:00:00  31.21
9/19/2012 16:00:00  31.19
9/20/2012 16:00:00  NaN
9/21/2012 16:00:00  31.61
9/24/2012 16:00:00  31.07
9/25/2012 16:00:00  31
9/26/2012 16:00:00  30.6
9/27/2012 16:00:00  30.4
9/28/2012 16:00:00  30.26
10/1/2012 16:00:00  29.98
10/2/2012 16:00:00  29.89
10/3/2012 16:00:00  29.99
10/4/2012 16:00:00  30.03
10/5/2012 16:00:00  30.25
10/8/2012 16:00:00  29.92
10/9/2012 16:00:00  NaN
10/10/2012 16:00:00 NaN
10/11/2012 16:00:00 29.25
10/12/2012 16:00:00 29.32
10/15/2012 16:00:00 NaN
10/16/2012 16:00:00 29.74
10/17/2012 16:00:00 29.64
10/18/2012 16:00:00 29.73
10/19/2012 16:00:00 29.08
10/22/2012 16:00:00 28.83
10/23/2012 16:00:00 28.2
10/24/2012 16:00:00 28.2
10/25/2012 16:00:00 28.2
10/26/2012 16:00:00 28.34
10/31/2012 16:00:00 NaN
11/1/2012 16:00:00  29.56
11/2/2012 16:00:00  29.77
11/5/2012 16:00:00  29.74
11/6/2012 16:00:00  NaN
11/7/2012 16:00:00  29.825
11/8/2012 16:00:00  29.37
11/9/2012 16:00:00  29.19
11/12/2012 16:00:00 29.01
11/13/2012 16:00:00 NaN
11/14/2012 16:00:00 27.29
11/15/2012 16:00:00 26.97
11/16/2012 16:00:00 NaN
11/19/2012 16:00:00 26.8
11/20/2012 16:00:00 26.8
11/21/2012 16:00:00 27.1666
11/23/2012 13:00:00 27.77
11/26/2012 16:00:00 27.58
11/27/2012 16:00:00 27.38
11/28/2012 16:00:00 27.39
11/29/2012 16:00:00 27.36
11/30/2012 16:00:00 27.13
12/3/2012 16:00:00  26.82
12/4/2012 16:00:00  26.63
12/5/2012 16:00:00  26.93
12/6/2012 16:00:00  26.98
12/7/2012 16:00:00  26.82
12/10/2012 16:00:00 26.97
12/11/2012 16:00:00 27.49
12/12/2012 16:00:00 27.62
12/13/2012 16:00:00 NaN
12/14/2012 16:00:00 27.13
12/17/2012 16:00:00 27.215
12/18/2012 16:00:00 27.63
12/19/2012 16:00:00 27.73
12/20/2012 16:00:00 27.68
12/21/2012 16:00:00 27.49
12/24/2012 13:00:00 27.25
12/26/2012 16:00:00 27.2
12/27/2012 16:00:00 27.09
12/28/2012 16:00:00 26.9
12/31/2012 16:00:00 26.77
```

Comment: Use interpolate() with datetime Index

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful. Specifically, please show us what you have tried so far and where you had issues

Answer (score 0):

The interpolate method fills NAs with a linear estimate by default, but it can be setup to use datetime. The [docs are here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html). Below is an example using a few rows of your data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {"val":[32.15, np.NaN, 32.09, 32.11, np.NaN, 32.7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=["3/20/2012 16:00:00", "3/21/2012 16:00:00", "3/22/2012 16:00:00", "3/23/2012 16:00:00", "3/26/2012 16:00:00", "3/27/2012 16:00:00" ])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
print(df)
                       val
2012-03-20 16:00:00  32.15
2012-03-21 16:00:00    NaN
2012-03-22 16:00:00  32.09
2012-03-23 16:00:00  32.11
2012-03-26 16:00:00    NaN
2012-03-27 16:00:00  32.70

df.interpolate(method="time", inplace=True)

print(df)
                         val
2012-03-20 16:00:00  32.1500
2012-03-21 16:00:00  32.1200
2012-03-22 16:00:00  32.0900
2012-03-23 16:00:00  32.1100
2012-03-26 16:00:00  32.5525
2012-03-27 16:00:00  32.7000
```